# Find representation set of orbits when group acts on a set

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, group-actions

Let group $G$ acts on a set $S$. Burnside's lemma gives as how to count numbers of orbits. I am interested how to find the orbits. By finding orbits I mean how to find a representative from each orbit.

Let there are $k$ orbits. We can call ${s_1,\ldots,s_k}\in S$ a representation set if none of them can be generated when $G$ group acts on the other and every orbit has representative.

As a algorithm one can choose the following. Mark all elements of $S$ unchecked. At each step get one unchecked element of $S$, put it in representation set, act group $G$ on it, get all resulting elements and make them checked. Continue until all elements are checked.

I am especially interested in finding orbit representatives in the following problem: 
$G$ is a group generated by cycle $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ and $S$ is the set of mappings from set $N=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $N=\{1,2,\ldots,r\}$. The action of group element $\alpha$ on mapping $f$ is the following:
$(\alpha f)(i)=f(\alpha(i))$.

Are there any results of better algorithms for finding representation set in general or for this specific case?

Comment: In general, computing $X/G$ for a $G$-set $X$ is pretty difficult. I'm assuming your group $G$ is finite?

Comment: Before asking about an algorithm, you need to specify how you input the group action.

Comment: Yes it is the group generated by $n$-length cycle permutation. It has $n$ powers of $(1,2,\ldots,n)$

Comment: @YCor We can assume that there is a function that gets element of $g\in G$ and element of $s\in S$ and returns the result when $g$ acts on $s$. By better algorithm I mean algorithm that calls that function less.

Comment: @Ashot So you mean $G,S$ are fixed beforehand once and for all, and computation of the group law and the action map are completely part of the input data?

Comment: In general we can assume that they are known and part of the input. But for the specific case (the action I described at the end of question) all that functions are defined and maybe there are some tricks that work in that specific case. Any help will be useful.

Comment: The action you have written down at the end is not a left action.

Comment: A relevant paper is https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0202006?journalCode=smjcat.

Comment: @AlexB. I think it is in this case, because $G$ is abelian. It would not be in general.

Comment: @Derek Holt: oops, right!

Comment: I think there are two separate questions here, which are not really related, so it makes it hard to know what you are asking. The first is asking about an algorithm for finding representatives of orbits. The second is to find representatives of the orbits of a specific class of examples.

Comment: I posted another question here with description for the specific case https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156893/algorithm-to-find-representatives-of-orbits-when-group-of-permutations-acts-on-s